# Some troubles during send emails

Tags: .net, smtpclient

I have the following class:

```
public class Email
{
    public System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient SmtpClient
    {
        get
        {
            if (_client == null)
            {
                    _client = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();
            }
            return _client;
        }
    }
}
```

and use it

```
    static Email email = new Email();
```

(in method)

```
                    email.SmtpClient.Send(message);
```

and after some calls of this code I get exception:

> Service not available, closing transmission channel. The server
>   response was: 4.4.2 service timed out.

why?

Comment: The thrown exception should have some information on why it couldn't be sent.  If you attach a debugger and look at the details it should have some more information. Could you please post that so we can help you out?

Comment: Service not available, closing transmission channel. The server response was: 4.4.2 service timed out.

Comment: That sounds like you are having a connection issue. Have you verifiied you can manually connect to the server from the machine you are running the tests on?  Also try disabling firewall temporarily to see if that fixes the problem

Comment: I don't get this error if I create client each time...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error can be because you exceed the `MessageRateLimitExceeded` (which limits how fast you can send multiple messages) or the connection has dropped. 
There is also other configuration parameters on SMTP servers which can limit how many and how much data you can send per session. The SmtpClient also manage connections in a pool,
so I think it's better to create a new client after you have sent few messages. You must also Dispose the client to ensure the client sends a QUIT message to servers.

For more information about error situations, read this [MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee220108%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx).